# workaround to read proper dimension when display : 'none'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Are there any workarounds to read proper element dimensions when it's `display` value is set to `none`?

Well, one would be to hide it without changing the `display`, but `visibility` property instead. While it gives proper dimensions, the element affects document flow.

One more way I can think of is `opacity`, but then the browser support kicks in.

The element I'm working with is appended to `body`.

Oh yes, I'm looking for computed style. There are no static CSS properties set for dimensions etc.

Any other solutions?

Comment: Why, what's the problem? Is `.width()` not giving the right dimensions? It is for me: http://jsfiddle.net/TLSte/

Comment: Try using `visibility: hidden;` and `position: absolute;`. The latter should keep it from affecting document flow.

Comment: @Pekka, if the element is `:hidden`/`display: none` (`.hide()`) it returns incorrect values.

Comment: @Jordan, actually that's what I was using, but forgot if you do not specify `left/top` coordinates for element, it stays like it'd flow with document. Just now remembered. @Pekka, please see @Justin's answer.

Comment: Ah, okay - it indeed shows wrong values for elements that are `display: inline` natively.

Comment: Can't you just read the dimensions immediately _after_ the DOM loads but _before_ setting it to `display:none;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `display` is none, by definition <strike>elements</strike> **non-block elements** have no dimensions. *(Thanks, @Pekka)* One potential way around this is to position the element far off-screen by setting `position: absolute` and `left: -999em`. The element will still exist so you can get its dimensions, but it won't appear in the document and should not affect flow.

Comment: The first sentence is not really correct: `.width()` still manages to retrieve the correct width for block elements. Not so much for inline ones, though

Comment: This has a potential problem though: `position: absolute` takes the element out of the document flow and can potentially change the width of a `div` with no width set - inside the document flow, it would take up 100% of the available space. That space can be different outside

Comment: @Pekka: Valid points all. The fact that the OP is looking for computed style makes this an interesting problem indeed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it with offsetHeight and javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
onload=function() {

var divh = document.getElementById('top').offsetHeight;

     alert(divh +"px");

 }
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: That is an option but only in situations where the object has a specific pixel-set height in CSS.